# Correctly override setter in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I just tried to override the standard synthesised setters of a property. So far everything is fine I just set the ivar to my new value. But then I asked myself 'what happens with the retain count of retained properties'... I found no good answer that explained this to me. So I ask it here. Is there anything I have to be aware of if I override a properties setter that is set to `retain` and how can I do it correctly? I do not use ARC.

Here's an example:

```
@property(nonatomic)NSInteger number;

- (void)setNumber:(NSInteger)number {
    _number = number;  // This should be fine, since it's no retained object I want to set
}


@property(nonatomic, retain)NSObject *something;

- (void)setSomething:(NSObject *)something {
    _something = something;  // This is not fine. As far as I know you should never do sth. like this... But how do I set it correctly?
}
```

Comment: From the usage of `retain` I gather that you're not using ARC?

Comment: you just have to set the retain count yourself - that's all

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
-(void) setAnObject:(NSObject*) someObject {
    if (_anObject != someObject) {
       NSObject* savedObject = _anObject;
       _anObject = [someObject retain];
       [savedObject release];
    }
}
```

If you release the old pointer before retaining the new, you can have a situation where you're setting the value from a value in the old object, and the release of the old object causes the new object to go POOF! just before it's retained.

Alternatively, you could do

```
....
[someObject retain];
[_anObject release];
_anObject = someObject;
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you overwriting the setters just to have a different name? If that's the case you can do so by changing the property definition:

```
@property(nonatomic, setter = nameOfSetter: )NSInteger number;
```

Same works for getter.

Comment: I know that, but thanks. No, I don't want to give them just another name. I want to add custom code to the setter.

Answer (score 5):

Edited after studying accepted answer from Hot Licks

property declaration and synthesis of x

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ClassX x;
@synthesize x = _x;
```

over-ridden setter for x

```
- (void)setX:(ClassX *)x;
{
  if (x != _x)
  {
    [x retain];
    [_x release];
    _x = x;
    // custom code here
  }
}
```

Comment: But imagine if you do `self.x = [self.x objectAtIndex:0];`.

Comment: self.x = [self.x objectAtIndex:0]; is just messing with my head :-)

Comment: The problem (for those who haven't got it yet, is that the result from `objectAtIndex` is only being retained by the current object (presumably an NSArray) in `x`.  If `setX` releases the current object and only then retains the new value, the NSArray *and all the objects in it* will be released, meaning that the value about to be set into `x` will be released.  This could result in some rather obscure and frustrating bugs.

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void) setSomething:(NSObject*) something
{
    if (something != _something)
    {
        [_something release];
        _something = [something retain];
    }
}
```

You need the `if` statement because otherwise, if something and _something were *already* the same, you'd overrelease the object, have it possibly disappear, and have problems.

Comment: Uh, but an NSInteger is not an object.

Comment: Still fails for `self.something = [self.something objectAtIndex:0];`